# Conversion to unit8 data class in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am new to matlab in beginner phase. I want to know that

How to convert a (2*3) matrix having values out side the range [0 255] to an uint8?

I am trying to convert it to unit8 data class but it gives me the following error with the following syntax.
B=unit8(A). where `A is 2*3 Matrix values [4 5 6 ; 2 4 5]`

> error: 
>   Undefined function 'unit8' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: It's `uint8`, not `unit8`. And how do you want to handle values greater than 255? They will be _clipped_ when converting to `uint8`, is that what you want?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html yeah it's a spelling error on your part

Comment: Yes thank You Brother.. It was spelling Mistake /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is spelling Mistake. it is `uint8` not `unit8`